# Maven build error "Found duplicate and different classes in [jackson-annotations, jackson-core, jackson-databind]" all at 2.10.0

Tags: java, maven, jackson, jackson-databind

I upgraded my jackson-databind maven reference from 2.9.9.3 to 2.10.0 to get past some security vulnerabilities. To overcome some implementation issues, I also had to upgrade jackson-core and jackson-annotation to 2.10.0. Now I'm getting a maven duplicatate finder which mentions all 3 jars.

I tried using the .prX releases that are mentioned in the maven repo. Changing the order of which jar is referenced in my pom.

```xml
<properties>
    <fasterxml-jackson.version>2.10.0</fasterxml-jackson.version>
    <fasterxml-jackson-databind.version>2.10.0</fasterxml-jackson-databind.version>
        ...
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
         <version>${fasterxml-jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
         <version>${fasterxml-jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
         <version>${fasterxml-jackson-databind.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
```

Now I'm getting the following issues when building:

```
[WARNING] Found duplicate and different classes in [com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.0, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0.pr3]:
[WARNING]   module-info
[WARNING] Found duplicate classes/resources in compile classpath.
[WARNING] Found duplicate and different classes in [com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.0, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0.pr3]:
[WARNING]   module-info
[WARNING] Found duplicate classes/resources in runtime classpath.
[WARNING] Found duplicate and different classes in [com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.0, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0.pr3]:
[WARNING]   module-info
[WARNING] Found duplicate classes/resources in test classpath.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.basepom.maven:duplicate-finder-maven-plugin:1.2.1:check (default) on project my-project: Found duplicate classes/resources! -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

if you don't mind conflicting classes:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.ning.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>duplicate-finder-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <failBuildInCaseOfConflict>false</failBuildInCaseOfConflict>
    ...
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but, if you want to fix the problem you have to check your dependencies and ignore some of them:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.ning.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>duplicate-finder-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <ignoredDependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.02</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.03</version>
      </dependency>
    </ignoredDependencies>
    ...
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

more info in the official [docs](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin)

Comment: Shouldn't the value of "failBuildInCaseOfConflict" be false.